# Gostaria de saber maneiras mais rápidas para executar a inserção de informações em uma coluna baseado no valor de outra

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Possuo um Dataframe com inúmeras colunas, mas para a seguinte questão as colunas importantes são:

- ID (número) do relato
- Produto
- Evento

Exemplo:

| id_relato | evento | produto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | edema | medicamento1 |
| 456 | prurido |  |
| 456 | sonolência |  |
| 789 | eritema | medicamento2 |
| 789 | tontura |  |

Um mesmo relato de um produto pode conter mais de 1 Evento e por isso, pode conter mais de 1 linha. Porém, o produto não é preenchido nas outras linhas, somente na primeira e por isso fiz um for loop para inserir o nome desse produto nessas outras linhas da coluna de Produto.

```
for i in relatos['id_elato']:
   relatos.loc[relatos['id_elato'] == i, 'produto'] = list(relatos.loc[relatos['id_elato'] == i]['produto'].unique())[0]
```

Resultado:

| id_relato | evento | produto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | edema | medicamento1 |
| 456 | prurido | medicamento1 |
| 456 | sonolência | medicamento1 |
| 789 | eritema | medicamento2 |
| 789 | tontura | medicamento2 |

Consigo o resultado esperado, porém, em um dataframe maior o processamento fica bem demorado. Por isso, haveria alternativas com melhor desempenho do que o for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que os campos produto estão em branco, ou seja string vazia (""). Siga os passos abaixo:

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id_relato": [456, 456, 456, 789, 789], "evento": ["edema", "prurido", "sonolência", "eritema", "tontura"], "produto": ["medicamento1", "", "", "medicamento2", ""]})

df

   id_relato      evento       produto
0        456       edema  medicamento1
1        456     prurido
2        456  sonolência
3        789     eritema  medicamento2
4        789     tontura
```

### Substituindo a string vazia por NaN

```
import numpy as np

df["produto"] = df["produto"].replace("", np.nan)

df

   id_relato      evento       produto
0        456       edema  medicamento1
1        456     prurido           NaN
2        456  sonolência           NaN
3        789     eritema  medicamento2
4        789     tontura           NaN
```

### Usando `fillna` com o método `ffill` (forward fill)

```
df = df.fillna(method="ffill")

df
   id_relato      evento       produto
0        456       edema  medicamento1
1        456     prurido  medicamento1
2        456  sonolência  medicamento1
3        789     eritema  medicamento2
4        789     tontura  medicamento2
```